# Code to add a C# class file to a project

Tags: c#

Can anybody provide some code block to add an existing C# file to a project.

I have 2 projects in my solution. One project generates C# class files which will be use by second project. I have to incluse these generated files in the second project and build the project. It should be done through programatically. I know that to include these files I have to edit the C#project file (which is an XML) and make an entry that file. But I thought of 
using existing code if anybody has it.

Thanks

Comment: Make dll from one application and add it to another!

Comment: this might help: [Adding files to .csproj programmatically](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/243377-adding-files-csproj-programmatically). I've not tried it, so I don't want to write an answer.

Comment: If you'd read my comment on your earlier closed question before deleting it, you would have had an answer.

Comment: @Likurg: I don't think I can use DLL. When I am compiling my second project by that it should have the auto generated files. If I am adding a DLL, it can only add those files when I ran the application.

Comment: @Likurg: I think Naresh wants to add the files at design time. Link a dynamic linking from files into another project.

Comment: As MatthiasG said I want to add files at design time.

Comment: Did it editing .csproj file. Making entries of new files in .csproj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ahve a look at the [MsBuild.Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.aspx) namespace. It allows you to manipulate a csproj in a consistent way so you can oper the target project and add the reference programmatically.

Comment: Did is editing .csproj file. Making entris in .csproj file which is a xml file.